# How to transform unknown data to be able to predict on models?

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

I am working on a loan status detector and have been using OneHotEncoding to encode some categorical columns. I went from X being 11, to X being 17 with the encoding. I am now testing my model on unknown data using a new dataframe of 11 variable, fit-transforming it using the encoder, which I would assume would result in 17 columns instead of 11. But I get an error saying the model expects 17 variables. How can I use the columns transformer to change it to 17 the way it worked when creating my X and y variables for the models?

```
X_new = [['Male','No',0,'Graduate','No',5849,0.0,128.0,360.0,1.0,'Urban']]

X_new = pd.DataFrame(X_new, columns= [too long to type]

column_trans = make_column_transformer(
    (OneHotEncoder(), ['Gender', 'Married', 'Education',
                  'Self_Employed','Property_Area']),
    remainder='passthrough')

column_trans.fit_transform(X_new)

clf.predict(X_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `fit_transform` doesn't change the input variable. You need to assign it to be able to pass it to `predict`:

```
transformed_cols = column_trans.fit_transform(X_new)
clf.predict(transformed_cols)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still getting the error that says the prediction is expecting 17 features